# NodeJS and MongoDB update array in document

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I've following code:

```
exports.addUser = function(req, res, next) {
  req.assert('email', 'Email is not valid').isEmail();
  req.assert('password', 'Password must be at least 4 characters long').len(4);
  req.assert('confirmPassword', 'Passwords do not match').equals(req.body.password);
  req.assert('firstName','First Name is empty').notEmpty();
  req.assert('lastName','Last Name is empty').notEmpty();

  var errors = req.validationErrors();

  if (errors) {
    req.flash('errors', errors);
    return res.redirect('/user/account-users/add');
  }

  var user = new User({    
    email: req.body.email,
    password: req.body.password,    
    profile: {
      role: req.body.role,
      firstName: req.body.firstName,
      lastName: req.body.lastName,
      screenName: req.body.screenName,
      addressOne: req.body.addressOne,
      addressTwo: req.body.addressTwo,
      country: req.body.country,
      stateProvince: req.body.stateProvince,
      postalCode: req.body.postalCode
    }
  });

  User.findOne({ email: req.body.email }, function(err, existingUser) {
    if (existingUser) {
      req.flash('errors', { msg: 'Account with that email address already exists.' });
      return res.redirect('/user/account-users/add');
    }
    user.save(function(err) {
      if (err) return next(err);

      Account.findOne( { users: { $elemMatch: { _id: req.user._id } } }, function(err, account) {
        var accountId = account._id;
        if(err) req.flash('errors', err);
        Account.update( { _id: accountId }, { users: { $push: user } }, function(err, result){
          console.log(result)
          if (err) return next(err);
          res.redirect('/user/account-users');
        });
      }); 
    });
  });
};
```

Currently when user add another user to his account this code clear account document where user is added.

How to properly add new created *user* to Account document where current user belong?

Comment: I don't see where [user] is being created.  The anonymous callback function in the first line returns [existingUser].  It looks like you're trying to push this [user] document into a users array found in a document in the Accounts collection.

Comment: @MichaelBlankenship I've user, I just not put it in comment. Now I've added full request inf first post.

Comment: If that's the case, then in this part [Account.update( { _id: accountId }, { users: { $push: user } }, ]... I'm guessing that you've selected to update the entire document rather than just the part you'd like to insert into that array.  What you may need to do there is to findOne() that same document, save its information, modify in place the saved information and then use it to update the stored document.